# how to change the attribute of CController::createUrl() dynamically

Tags: jquery, yii

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
        'name'=>'searchlocation',
        'id'=>'searchlocation',
        'value'=>'',
        'source'=>CController::createUrl('/home/findLocation',
            array(
                'cityid' => 'js: $('#hiddenField').val()',
            )
        ),
        'options'=>array(
            'showAnim'=>'fold',         
            'minLength'=>'1',
            'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
                $("#searchlocation").val( ui.item.label );
                $("#hiddenlocationid").val( ui.item.location_id );
                return false;
            }',
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'onfocus' => 'js: this.value = null; 
                $("#searchlocation").val(null);         
                $("#hiddenlocationid").val(null);',
            'class' => 'input-xxlarge search-query',
            'placeholder' => "Your Location",
        ),
    ));
```

I want to access the hidden field value and assign to `cityid` dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the third option of javascript callback in the source documentation..http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiAutoComplete#source-detail

```
'source'=>
    CJavaScriptExpression::code(
        "$.getJSON(
            ".CController::createUrl('/home/findLocation').", 
            {cityid: $('#hiddenField').val()}
            function(data) { return data; }
         )",
    ),
```

NOT TESTED

Comment: @JoginderSharma did it work? Sorry didn't get time to test..if it is then accept the answer..:)